# Are pure functions supported by MATLAB Symbolic Toolbox?

Tags: matlab

Are pure functions of Mathematica implemented somehow in MATLAB Symbolic Toolbox? I would like to calculate nested differentiations.

A simple example:
I would like to get the directional derivative of a 2D function int the direction of the largest change.

```
syms f x y w
w = [ diff(f,x); diff(f,y) ] / sqrt(diff(f,x) + diff(f,y));
d = w * [ diff(f,x), diff(f,y) ];
```

I would like to get the answer:

```
d = sqrt(diff(f,x)^2 + diff(f,y)^2);
```

This doesn't work, because MATLAB evaluates diff(f,x)=diff(f,y)=0 (it doesn't know if it is a function). Is MATLAB symbolic toolbox capable of something like I would like to achieve?

Comment: Do you know what `f` is? Or do you want it in terms of a general `f`?

Comment: No. It's an arbitrary differentible function of x and y.

Comment: I forgot to get back to you after my comment... Please see my answer below. I don't think what you're trying to do is possible in MATLAB, but I'd be happy to know if it's otherwise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your question:

> This doesn't work, because MATLAB evaluates diff(f,x)=diff(f,y)=0 (it doesn't know if it is a function).

This is not an abnormal behaviour, rather the expected one. When you initialize `f` to be a symbolic variable, there is no definition associated with `f` and hence a derivative w.r.t `x` *should* return `0` and a derivative w.r.t. itself *should* return `1`. Mathematica behaves exactly the same:

#### MATLAB:

```
syms f x
diff(f,x)
 
ans =
 
0

diff(f,f)
 
ans =
 
1
```

#### Mathematica

```
In[1]:= D[f, x]
        D[f, f]

Out[1]= 0
Out[2]= 1
```

With pure functions, the definition is independent of the actual function and if you chuck in any argument, it should evaluate it. For e.g., the pure function definition of a derivative w.r.t. `x` in mathematica, `D[#, x] &`

```
In[3]:= D[#, x] &[a x^2 + b x + c]
Out[3]= 2 a x

In[4]:= D[#, x] &[a x^3 + b f]
Out[4]= 3 a x^2
```

The closest equivalent of this in MATLAB is called an [anonymous function](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/matlab_prog/f4-70115.html). The definition for the above function is

```
syms f x a b c
y=@(f)diff(f,x);

y(a*x^2+b*x+c)

ans =
 
b + 2*a*x
```

Now coming to what you wanted to do, it is possible in Mathematica to hold certain expressions unevaluated and massage it to get it in the final output form that you want. However, I'm not aware of such a capability in MATLAB using the symbolic toolbox.